# How can I upload this custom font to a static html page

Tags: html, css, fonts

total newbie at html here.
Im looking to incorperate any one of these fonts from:
https://andrewsonline.co.uk/content/fonts/
into a static github page im making for a website.
I see the css code for these fonts is here:
https://andrewsonline.co.uk/content/fonts/fonts.css
Do I just need to copy and paste this into my html?
Where do I place the eot, woff, tff and svg files?

Thankyou for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter **where** you place the fonts, so long as they are referenced correctly:

- The prefix `/` is relative to the root directory.
- The prefix `./` is relative to the working directory.
- The prefix `../` is relative to the parent directory.

Just make sure to define the font in a `@font-face`, specifying the desired name in `font-family`, and the URL of the font in the `src` attribute. The only font URL that you need to link to is the **`.woff`** (the others are just browser-specific alternatives or outdated extensions).

Typically, you would just use something similar to the following:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: externalFont;
    src: url(/fonts/GT-Walsheim-Pro-Light.woff);
}

div {
    font-family: externalFont;
}
```

```html
<div>Stylish</div>
```

Note that Andrew's Online have set up a "No Access-Control-Allow-Origin", meaning that the font inclusion would be blocked by [**CORS**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) policy if you were to link to their fonts directly. You'll need to **download** their fonts, then link to a **local** copy.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for the response. Yep so I downloaded the woff file, where would I put it exactly? Within my folder? http://imgur.com/a/uMwgU I am trying to replace the custom google fonts in https://github.com/syunghong/veil/blob/master/thumbnail-gallery.html  , so where would I put it in the html?

Comment: Like I say, you can place it wherever you'd like. Given that **specific** structure, I would recommend creating a folder called `fonts`, and then referencing the `fonts` folder with a root-relative link like in my example. All you'll need to do is change the name of the font in the above example, and that should work for you. And you'll need **CSS** to change a font; you'll need to write the code in a CSS file, and then reference the CSS file in your HTML.

Comment: Ok got it. So I take what you've written above and put it in a css file and then put that in my css folder, is that right? How would I reference it and where?

Comment: I'm afraid that's not even **close** to right =\ Create a **folder** called `fonts` in your **root** directory, so that it's at the same level as `js` and `img`. Then add the **top box** of what I wrote into **`style.css`**. Considering your structure, `style.css` is probably already linked correctly. The bottom box of my code is the **HTML**; showcasing a sample of how it would be used. Note that the `div { }` part of my CSS indicates that the font should only affect `<div>` elements in the HTML. If you want it to affect other elements, you'll need to modify your CSS selector to suit.

Comment: Also, considering you were trying to add HTML to a CSS file, I'd strongly recommend taking a look at the [**basics of HTML**](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_intro.asp) and the [**basics of CSS**](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_intro.asp) in order to familiarise yourself with both of them a little better :)

Comment: Whoops, I see. So in the style.css it says `font-family: Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;`, so I just change this with what youve written in the top box?  Yeah...bit of a newbie